# Need to display two items at a time within a Recyclerview horizontal orientation

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Hello guys I would like to make my RecyclerView horizontal scroll with showing at a time 2 items.
like this, in the 3rd position, I need to show RecyclerView horizontal list and show 2 items with auto fix with screen width(which means I don't want to set item width).

It's my XML Layout code.

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerviewMyHops"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:visibility="visible"
      app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
       />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your .kt file set:

```
recyclerView?.apply{
   layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(view.requireContext(), 2);
}
```

the second parameter is spanCount and is setting the number of columns in the grid.

Comment: I want only horizontal scrolling with showing 2 items at a time.

Comment: you can pass a third parameter that is the orientation of recyclerview, and then will scroll horizontally

Comment: Ok I will try this.